# Jquery .slideToggle() with CSS media query

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a mobile version of my website that changes according to the width, when the mobile width triggers the media query changes the menu to a drop down. The problem I am having is when a user click on the drop down and then hides it again, when expanding width to full view the menu remains hidden.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#drop_button")
    .click(function(){
        $("#menu").stop();
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    width:30%;  
    float:left;
}

@media (max-device-width: 380px), (max-width: 380px){
    #menu{
        display:none;
        width:calc(100% - 20px);
        height:auto;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:1em;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your css for the full view styles of  the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was hoping to this in CSS however I have used Jquery:

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 380){
            $("#menu").css("display","inline");
            //Ensure menu is always visible if the window width is larger than 380px.
        }
        else
        {
            $("#menu").css("display","none");
            //Hide the menu any time the window is resized.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

`.slideToggle()` is messing with the CSS's `display` property.

There are a couple of ways to accomplish what you need, one is to:
Style with CSS **Mobile-first** (the other-way-around)
and use `!important` to override the styles added by jQuery `slideToggle`:

```
#menu{                      /* Mobile-first */
  background:#faf;
  display:none;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
}
#drop_button{display:block;}

@media (min-width: 380px){    /* non-mobile Media Query */
  #menu{
    display:block !important; /* override jQuery styles */
    width:30%;  
    float:left;
  }
  #drop_button{display:none;}
}
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/jutebi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

You'll still have a small issue you did not mentioned, and that's:
that if you open the Menu while Mobile, than you go to Desktop and back to Mobile, the Menu will *wait* you opened instead of being always *hidden*.
***To fix that*** you can create a `$(window).on("resize", fn)` listener, get the viewport size and hide the menu (if was opened before on Mobile)